# Two Input Files to One Output

Tags: gulp

I have a program that takes two files one output.

Say I have gulp find the files `input1.json`, `input1.xml`, `input2.json`, and `input2.xml`. How can I then pass these files in pairs to the output to produce `input1.output` and `input2.output`?

The base filenames will always be the same, so it is just a case of pairing the files by the basenames, but I cannot use a fixed array of files to pick from.

The files cannot be concatenated or included in each other in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below. This should work as is. Just plug it in and see if it helps you out. I think it does what you need it to do. Please let me know how it goes.

```
gulp.task('myTask', function() {
  var dir      = "<MY BASE DIR>";
  var streams  = [];
  var basename = "input";
  var counter  = 1;

  var jsonFile = path.join(dir, basename + (counter++) + ".json");
  while (fs.existsSync(jsonFile)) {
    // Iterate through as many files as you have
    var stream = gulp.src(jsonFile)
                  .pipe(through.obj(function(jsonFile, enc, callback) {
                      var xmlFilepath = path.join(dir, path.basename(jsonFile.path, ".json") + ".xml");
                      var xmlContents = fs.readFileSync(xmlFilepath);
                      var xmlFile = new plugins.util.File({path: xmlFilepath, contents: xmlContents});

                      // You now have access to both the json and the xml file
                      this.push(jsonFile);
                      this.push(xmlFile);

                      callback();
                  }))
                  .pipe(plugins.rename(function(path){
                    // This will only affect one single file per pair
                    path.extname = '.output';
                  }))
                  .pipe(gulp.dest(dir));
    streams.push(stream);

    // Keep looking for more files
    jsonFile = path.join(dir, basename + (counter++) + ".json");
 }

 return merge(streams);
}
```